# JQuery func inside JS func executed increasingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does a jQuery function inside a javascript function fire off increasingly for each time it's clicked? Clicked enough times it gets executed 100+ times per one click.

```
<div class="clickity" onclick="funky()">Test</div>

var x = 0;

function funky(){
    $('.clickity').on('click', function(){
        x += 1;
        alert(x);
    });
};
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwpvt18q/1/) I'm just curious about why it works this way.

Comment: Remove the `onclick="funky()"` and unwrap `$('.clickity').on('click', fn)` from a function declaration statement.

Answer (score 1):

Because every time you click on `clickity`, `funky` method is called and registers a new event listener on `clickity`. You're mixing two methods, either do:

```js
var x = 0;

function funky(){
    x += 1;
alert(x);
};
```

```html
<div class="clickity" onclick="funky()">Test</div>
```

or

```js
var x = 0;

$('.clickity').on('click', function(){
    x += 1;
alert(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickity" >Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, why insert the listener in the function? Every time you click add a new listener to the button. Every click execute the increment and add a new listener.

Comment: I was assigning an Id to onclick="func(id)" and using that id in my jquery $('.class'+id). so as not to have a for loop running each time I click or hover over an element to run hundreds of times just to find one number, will have to find a better solution tho :)

Answer (score 0):

The `addEventListener` a.k.a. `on` in `jQuery` has a cumulative aspect. You are not assign it by replacing the old one but adding a new one and keeping the previous handlers chain.

Answer (score 0):

You are combining class Javascript Onclick HTML attribute with jquery.

First round

1. user clicks clickity
2. a. funky is called because of HTML attribute onclick
3. funky attaches a listener to clickety.
4. note funky has not increased x on this first click.

Next round

1. user clicks clickity
2. a. funky is called because of HTML attribute onclick
3. b. x is incremented by 1 because of jquery event listener to clickety attached in first round
4. funky attaches a listener to clickety

Future rounds

1. user clicks clickity
2. a. funky is called because of HTML attribute onclick
3. b. x is incremented by 1 because of jquery event listener to clickety attached in first round
4. c. x is incremented by 1 because of jquery event listener to clickety attached in second round
5. funky attaches a listener to clickety